# Export data from SqlQuery to Excel sheet

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, export

I have the below Query and would like to know how do I import the results to an excel sheet from Sql server

This is what I have to import

```
select c.description as 'provider',
b.lastname, b.firstname, b.middleinitial, 
convert(varchar(10),b.dob,101) as DOB, b.chartID,
b.sex, d.businessname, d.businessfax
from patientappointmentbase as a, patientlistbase as b, 
resourcebase as c, locationbase as d
where convert(varchar(10),a.starttime,101) = '06/26/2013'
and a.patientid = b.patientid
and a.resourceid = c.resourceid
and a.locationid = d.locationid
order by provider, lastname, firstname
```

Comment: That does not look anything like that question

Comment: Can anyone let me know the usage of it as I have gone through this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx and could get an idea but getting difficulty in implementing through command line, can anyone provide me a sample related to my question..